# TradingView's Pinescript - why isn't recursion allowed?

Tags: pine-script

The [docs](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Declaring_functions.html) state:

> Pine Scipt functions do not support recursion. It is not allowed for a function to call itself from within its own code.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in Pine, in order to call a function, it must be completely defined in the code above the point you're calling it from. In a recursive function, you're trying to call that same function, before it's completely defined, so Pine doesn't "know" that function yet.

In the example below, `function_a()` can be called from within `function_b()`, because it's already defined when the compiler gets to `function_b()`, so it's "known" at that point.

However, `function_c()` cannot call `function_d()` because it's not defined yet at that point, causing the compiler to throw an error.

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Study", overlay=true)

function_a(n) => 2 * n
function_b(n) => 3 * function_a(n)
function_c(n) => 4 * function_d(n)
function_d(n) => 5 * n

plot(na)
```

The same applies to a recursive function, like the factorial calculation below.
The moment we're trying to call the `factorial()` function from within itself, the definition of that function isn't complete yet, so the function is "unknown" at that point in the code, causing the compiler to throw an error.

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Study", overlay=true)

factorial(n) => 
    if (n <= 1)
        1
    else
        n * factorial(n-1)

plot(na)
```